# How to get array id in ajax append?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have an appended, there a selectbox with 2 textbox

first the selectbox will selecting an item, after on change, it will set all the  textbox with data based on selected.
my select option calling data from database array $data.

this is my ajax code

```
 function getBarang(val) {
  
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "JSON/getBarang",
        // url: baseurl + "JSON/getVal" + val,
        type:"POST",
        data:{"get_barang":val},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data){
           
            $('#harga_jual').val((data[0].harga_jual));
            $('#stock_sisa').val((data[0].stock_sisa));

        }
    });
}
```

this is my form

```
echo '<select name="barang[]" id="barang-'.$row.'" class="s2barang form-control"  onchange="getBarang(this.value)">';
                            
echo (isset($dBarang->id_barang)) ? '<option value="' . $dBarang->id_barang.'">' . $dBarang->nama_barang . '</option>' : '';
echo                    '   </select> ';    
                            
echo '
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock_sisa" id="stock_sisa">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="harga_jual" id="harga_jual">
```

**lets pass about query data, because its worked.**
**and this is my view as result**
[image]

my second textbox not working, pls help me, thanks

Edited:
Let me explain more.
the target is textbox stock sisa, and textbox harga_jual
the $dBarang created like this, $row just like $i=0, for cheching last data on database

```
 $dataBarang = $this->m_db->getDataWhere("v_pembelian_detail","id_pembelian","'$id_p' ORDER BY id_pembelian_detail");
        $dataBarang = (empty($dataBarang)) ? [''] : $dataBarang;

        foreach ($dataBarang as $dBarang) 
        {
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: @Andreas Do you mean this one `id="barang-'.$row.'" `

Comment: You might tell us how `$dBarang` gets created and populated. Basically there is too much missing from this question. please remember we are not clairvoyant

Comment: @RiggsFolly How would this be not unique when there's `$row` in it? I'm talking about the hard coded `... id="stock_sisa">` and `... id="harga_jual">` that are the targets in the `success` handler

Comment: this is for dBarang created...$dataBarang = $this->m_db->getDataWhere("v_pembelian_detail","id_pembelian","'$id_p' ORDER BY id_pembelian_detail");
        $dataBarang = (empty($dataBarang)) ? [''] : $dataBarang;

        foreach ($dataBarang as $dBarang)

Comment: @Andreas yes i use it before, like id="stock_sisa"'.$row, this is just like id="stock_sisa1. But what im confused is about the ajax, how should i implement it??? the result without special id is like on my picture"

Comment: What hexactly do you mean by "not working"? Is this a frontend problem (in the browser) - then please share the **generated** markup - or a backend problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `this` as well inside your function where `this` refer to current select-box where change has been taken place. Then , using this you can use `$(el).closest('.outer').find('.harga_jual')..` to add input values to required inputs only.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//just for demo..
var data = [{
  "harga_jual": "soemthing",
  "stock_sisa": "soemthing1"
}]

function getBarang(val, el) {

  /*$.ajax({
    url: baseurl + "JSON/getBarang",
    // url: baseurl + "JSON/getVal" + val,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "get_barang": val
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {*/
  //get closest div > get input add value there..
  $(el).closest('.outer').find('.harga_jual').val(data[0].harga_jual);
  $(el).closest('.outer').find('.stock_sisa').val(data[0].stock_sisa);

  /* }
  });*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--add sme outer div-->
<div class="outer">
  <select name="barang[]" id="barang-'.$row.'" class="s2barang form-control" onchange="getBarang(this.value ,this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control stock_sisa" name="stock_sisa">
  <input type="text" class="form-control harga_jual" name="harga_jual">
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <select name="barang[]" id="barang-'.$row.'" class="s2barang form-control" onchange="getBarang(this.value ,this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control stock_sisa" name="stock_sisa">
  <input type="text" class="form-control harga_jual" name="harga_jual">
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <select name="barang[]" id="barang-'.$row.'" class="s2barang form-control" onchange="getBarang(this.value ,this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control stock_sisa" name="stock_sisa">
  <input type="text" class="form-control harga_jual" name="harga_jual">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, the find and this giving me a good way to clear my stuck

Answer (score -1):

this is what i get from changing my id to class

```
function getBarang(val) {
      
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + "JSON/getBarang",
            // url: baseurl + "JSON/getVal" + val,
            type:"POST",
            data:{"get_barang":val},
            dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data){
               
                $('.harga_jual').val((data[0].harga_jual));//before #harga_jual
                $('.stock_sisa').val((data[0].stock_sisa));//before #stock_sisa

            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

but the data seem the last selected and change to all :(
i want it each selected